# How can i filter and create ranges from NSIndexSet?

Tags: ios, objective-c

I have an NSIndexSet created by

```
NSIndexSet* groups = [self.specifiers indexesOfObjectsPassingTest:^(PSSpecifier*specifier, NSUInteger idx, BOOL *stop) {
return [(NSString*)[specifier.properties objectForKey:@"cell"] isEqualToString:@"KBGroupCell"]; }];
```

that could look something like this:

`(0 3 5 8-9 12 14 17-19)` and a given max of 25.

Im hoping to filter and create ranges, so that I can achieve an output looking like:

```
0-2
3-4
5-7
8-11
12-13
14-16
17-25
```

The Array used is filled by users and not by myself. KBGroupCells are used to populate headers and footers in a table so there shouldn't be consecutive recognised. I need to remember the ignored numbers (9, 18 and 19) when I populate my table later.

By using `rangeAtIndex` I can identify the the ranges in the set that contain more than one, so could possibly be used for finding the numbers to ignore.

How can I achieve this?

Comment: 1. What about `5-7`? 2. Please show your code for populating this `NSIndexSet`.

Comment: Let's say the index set contains `0 3 8-9 10 15`. Should the result be `0-2, 3-7, 8-14, 15-25` or `0-2, 3-7, 8-9, 10-14, 15-25`?

Comment: @rmaddy - Is not `NSIndexSet` a set of indices and the range notation just a way of describing it? So `0 3 8-9 10 15` is actually `0 3 8-10 15` and your question therefore moot? I think the OP wants to create ranges which start with the first index of a run of indices present in the set, such a run might have length 1, and end with the next index not in the set which immediately preceeds one which is (or immediately preceeds the end of the set).

Comment: @rmaddy you're very right. Not sure what happened to 5-7 have edited it back in. Sorry about that!

Comment: @rmaddy In that example it would be 0-2, 3-7, 8-9, 10-14, 15-25.

Noting that 9 will be ignored

Comment: You still need to update your question with the code that populates the `NSIndexSet` you want to process.

Comment: @rmaddy Have added the code used to populate the NSIndexSet. The Array used is filled by users and not by myself. There cant be multiple KBGroupCells in a row, but I need to remember any ignored ones when i populate my table later.

Comment: @CRD was correct also. It would have ended up being 8-10 rather then having 8-9 and 10. Due to 10 being incremental from 9

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I assume you have the NSIndexSet:

```
    let original =   IndexSet(arrayLiteral: 0, 3, 5).union(IndexSet(integersIn: 8...9)).union( IndexSet.init(arrayLiteral: 12,14)).union(IndexSet(integersIn: 17...19)).union(IndexSet.init(arrayLiteral: 26,27))
    let nsIndex = original as! NSIndexSet
```

After converting it to IndexSet and you can easily get two arrays. One is [NSRange] and the other is [closedRange]

```
    let index = nsIndex as! IndexSet
    let rangeView = index.rangeView
    print  ( Array(rangeView.enumerated().map{
      NSRange.init(location:($0.element.first!) , length: ((rangeView[$0.offset + 1].first!  - ($0.element.first!))))
    }.dropLast()))

    print  ( Array(rangeView.enumerated().map{
                ($0.element.first!)...(rangeView[$0.offset + 1].first!) - 1
        }.dropLast()))
```

If it's objective-C. Just like this:

```
NSMutableIndexSet * nsIndex =    [[NSMutableIndexSet alloc] init];
[nsIndex addIndex: 0];
[nsIndex addIndex: 3];
[nsIndex addIndex: 5];
[nsIndex addIndexesInRange:NSMakeRange(8, 2)];
[nsIndex addIndex: 12];
[nsIndex addIndex: 14];
[nsIndex addIndexesInRange:NSMakeRange(17, 3)];
[nsIndex addIndex: 26];
__block int count = 0;
__block NSMutableArray * ranges = [NSMutableArray array];
[nsIndex enumerateRangesUsingBlock:^(NSRange range, BOOL * _Nonnull stop) {
    count ++;
    [ranges addObject:[NSValue valueWithRange: range]];
}];
NSMutableArray * result  = [NSMutableArray array];
for (NSUInteger location = 0 ; location < count - 1 ; location++) {
    NSUInteger loc = ((NSValue *) ranges[location]).rangeValue.location;
    [result addObject:[NSValue valueWithRange: (NSMakeRange( loc,  ((NSValue *) ranges[location + 1]).rangeValue.location -  loc))]];
}
NSLog(result.description);
```

or With one round:

```
__block NSUInteger temp = nsIndex.firstIndex;
__block NSMutableArray * result = [NSMutableArray array];
[nsIndex enumerateRangesWithOptions:NSEnumerationReverse usingBlock:^(NSRange range, BOOL * _Nonnull stop) {
    [result insertObject: [NSValue valueWithRange: NSMakeRange(range.location, temp - range.location)] atIndex:0];
    temp = range.location ;
}];
  result =  [result subarrayWithRange:NSMakeRange(0, result.count - 1)];
  NSLog(result.description);
```

Comment: could you tell me how this ignores the values I dont want?  I would like to also add the ignored indexes to a separate array but im struggling to understand where exactly that happens.

Comment: If any range’s length in block > 1, collect NSMakeRange(range.location +1, range.length-1)

Answer (score 0):

Here is a possible algorithm, coding and some error checks are left as exercises!

```
cursor <- theSet first contained index
result <- empty array

while cursor <= maxIndex
   start <- cursor
   while cursor <= maxIndex and theSet contains cursor do increment cursor
   while cursor <= maxIndex and theSet does not contain cursor do increment cursor
   newRange <- start to cursor-1
   add newRange to result
end

return result
```

That algorithm uses just two methods of `NSIndexSet` - one to find the first index in the set and the other to test if an index is in the set. There are "higher level" methods which might speed up the algorithm, but with a range of 0-25 stepping through the indices should be sufficient.

HTH